# Set of linear transformations being a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces, $T$, $T_1$, and $T_2$ linear transformations from $V$ to $W$, and $k$ a scalar. We define new transformations $T_1 + T_2$ and $kT$ by the formulas:

$$(T_1 + T_2)(\vec x) = T_1(\vec x) + T_2(\vec x)$$

$$(kT)(\vec x) = k(T(\vec x))$$

We can easily prove that the aforementioned transformations are indeed linear (I only mention this because it was part of the problem).

My question: **How do we show that the set of all linear transformations from $V$ to $W$ with the operations stated previously form a vector space, and how do I approach this problem? What is it asking? Is there some formal or general way of determining this?**

Comment: I assume that somewhere in your course you have a definition of a vector space. Find that definition. It will have a list of conditions. Check that these definitions of addition and scalar multiplication satisfy those conditions, so make the set into a vector space. There is no formal or general way to do this - each case requires its own arguments to show that the conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already know that the set of linear transformations is closed under the addition and scalar multiplication you've been given, you only need to check the vector space axioms.

Is addition associative? Is there a zero element? Are there additive inverses? and so on. Other than that, there's not much to check.

Check out the Wikipedia page for the axioms:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space

Answer (score 0):

This a situation where a formal proof, while quite simple, will confuse more than help. I think your problem is not with formal application of logic and checking whether the axioms of a vector space are satisfied. (By the way, it's so easy to see that they are satisfied that it's difficult to see what the problem is asking.)

What I think you will enjoy understanding is the *spirit* of linear algebra. The spirit of linear algebra is that it studies objects of a particular kind that can be added together and multiplied by numbers to produce another object of the same kind. Any kind of objects that satisfy these governing required (along with a handful of other totally expected properties) is called a *vector*. Vectors include geometric vectors (arrows), polynomials or - more generally - functions, elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and, yes, transformations.

The fact that transformations can be added together and multiplied by numbers and therefore form a vector space is interesting but ultimately doesn't add much richness to the fabric of essential linear algebra. It's an important realization to make, but otherwise it is a killjoy of a question because it doesn't directly lead to any interesting connections. (By the way, the "linear" requirement is completely superfluous. Essentially, any set of functions closed under addition and multiplication by a number form a vector space.)

For a textbook that emphasizes this point view see Gelfand's "Lectures on Linear Algebra" or the Linear Algebra course on Lemma (http://lem.ma).